# Jenkins Pipeline refer a environment variable within environment variable section

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am creating two environment variables in my Jenkins Pipeline,

```
environment{
base_ver=sh(script: 'grep FROM ${WORKSPACE}/Dockerfile | awk -F : \'{print $2}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
git_hash=sh(script: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

Now I want to create another env variable in same section by using above two variables, it would we something like this
Image='$base_ver'-'$git_hash'
I tried multiple ways of doing it but none on them seems to work, can we access the env variable within env variable section?
Here is what I tried,

```
environment{
base_ver=sh(script: 'grep FROM ${WORKSPACE}/Dockerfile | awk -F : \'{print $2}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
git_hash=sh(script: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD', returnStdout: true).trim()
Image=sh(script: 'DockerImage=${base_ver}-${git_hash}', returnStdout: true).trim()

}
```

Please let me know if this is possible or right way of doing it.
Thanks .

Comment: These should be normal variables and not environment variables. That will help.

Answer (score 0):

What you currently doing is launching shell, defining variable in it and exiting. There is nothing printed and therefore stdout returned is empty.

Concatenation can be done by groovy. There is no need to launch shell for that.
Thy this:

`Image = base_ver + '-' + git_hash`

If you need to do it in shell for whatever reason just add echo (also note double quotes so that groovy substitute variables before calling shell):

`Image=sh(script: "echo -n '${base_ver}-${git_hash}'", returnStdout: true).trim()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it worked for me. Thank you guys for suggestion.

```
sh """
Image=${PROD_ECR_REPO}:${env.base_ver}-${env.git_hash}
echo \$Image
"""
```